# Check if multiple variables are not empty -PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

This is the code:

```
<?php if($variable !== '') { ?>
<?php echo $variable; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

What I want is that it checks if multiple variables are empty.

Thank you.

Comment: you want a function or the logic to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the logical and operator: `&&`:

```
<?php if ($var1 !== '' && $var2 !== '') { ?>
```

Also, you can place all of this script in one tag.

Comment: Can i put more && with some other operator..

Answer (score 8):

As you are comparing to an empty string (`!==''`), you can also use concatenation:

```
if (!empty($a . $b . $c))
```

By the way:

```
if($variable !== '') {
    echo $variable;
}
```

Is the same as just:

```
echo $variable;
```

Comment: I've been searching for an hour for a soltion to three !empty's in a single if statement, and only your answer worked for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you for this. This is the lightest way. Appreciate it. @jeroen

Comment: This doesn't work right `(empty($x[1] . $x[2])) !== (empty($x[1]) || empty($x[1]))`. You shouldn't use it unless $x[1] and $x[2] are set

Comment: $arr = [$var1, $var2, $var3];
if (count(array_filter($arr)) != count($arr)) {
 // one or more is empty}

Comment: what if $a is empty but not $b & $c? It would still return true!

Answer (score 4):

Use the empty() call in PHP.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

```
<?php if(!empty($variable)) { ?>
<?php echo $variable; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Yes this is probably right. But can't I do it with the code above?

Comment: Why not? I just modified your example.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [and (`&&`) operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

```
if ($a != '' && $b != '' && c != '')
    echo $a, $b, $c;
```